# Disable CSS transitions on window resize?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm surprised I can't find any solutions to this. I've got four square divs which are in a line at full-screen, in a 2x2 grid at mobile size. They change colour with a CSS transition on click.

But when I resize my window, they float about the page into their new positions - an unwanted side effect of the CSS transition. I've tried using JQuery to toggle the transitions while resizing, which keeps them from floating, but there's a 50% chance that the transition class will be inactive when you stop resizing!

I've not put any code in here as it seems like such a simple problem. Does anybody have any simple solutions?

Comment: use media query for this purpose

Comment: if you donot aware about media query, let me know

Comment: Are you able to reset state on javascript's resize event?  You can also use a small timeout for the transitions and then cancel the timeout on resize events.

Answer (score 13):

When the window is resizing, we can add to < body > a special CSS-class "stop-transitions".
After resizing and short timeout we removed this class. Put this before closing tag < body >:

```
<script>
    (function() { 
        const classes = document.body.classList;
        let timer = 0;
        window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
            }
            else
                classes.add('stop-transitions');

            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                classes.remove('stop-transitions');
                timer = null;
            }, 100);
        });
    })();
</script>
```

And add next to your CSS. It resets the transition property for all during the resize. After resize and short timeout this class will removed and the transition works again.

```
body.stop-transitions * {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Comment: just came across this thumbs up

Answer (score 9):

If you use `transition: all 200ms ease-out` as opposed to `transition: color 200ms ease-out` you're applying transitions to all properties, instead of just one specific property.

Comment: ... and that's my simple solution! Awesome - thanks - can't believe I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Dmitry's wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55732883/18620006). Here is a way to do the same thing, but in a declarative manner, if you are using React as a framework. It requires very little extra configuration, and removes the need to have special classes(or even a CSS file!) altogether.

```js
    function ComponentFoo(){
      const [resizing,setResizing]=useState(false);

      useEffect(()=>{
        let timer;
        function SetResizingState() {
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            else setResizing(true);

            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                setResizing(false);
            }, 100);
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', SetResizingState);

        // remove the event listener when component is unmounted
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize',SetResizingState);
      },[])
      return (
      <div
        style={{
          transition: resizing ? 'none' : '',
        }}
      ></div> 
      )
    }
```

You can add the transitions that you need normally either inside classNames prop, or as a part of a styled component declaration, or in place of the blank space given in the ternary operator here. Either way, the `transition:'none'` will be applied as an inline style, and so has highest precedence.